# mpirun python3 mpi4py runs in serial instead of parallel

Tags: python-3.x, mpi4py

I try to run the example

```
mpiexec -n 5 python -m mpi4py.bench helloworld
```

that works well on my local computer, on a cluster.

However, on the cluster it simply runs in serial several times.

```
$ mpiexec --version
Intel(R) MPI Library for Linux* OS, Version 2021.5 Build 20211102 (id: 9279b7d62)
Copyright 2003-2021, Intel Corporation.
$ python --version
Python 3.8.5
$ pip show mpi4py
Name: mpi4py
Version: 3.1.3
Summary: Python bindings for MPI
Home-page: https://github.com/mpi4py/mpi4py/
Author: Lisandro Dalcin
Author-email: dalcinl@gmail.com
License: BSD
Location: /mn/stornext/d13/euclid/oyvinch/pyenv/main/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Requires:
Required-by: mpsort, nbodykit, pfft-python, pmesh
```

Does anyone have any input?

Comment: Probably the the mpi executable is wrong with respect to the mpi4py one. I made it run by using the executable inside of the python bin

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using python 3 try running it in terminal as
`mpiexec -n 4 python3 yourfile.py`